# Ruby on Rails Tutorial ... on Rails New and Rails Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I'm following Rails Tutorial using Cloud9  ...

Tutorial says to install Rails 4.2.2. Before I did, I ran "rails -v" and saw that it was 4.2.1.

I ran Gem install Rails 4.2.2 and a load of stuff was installed. Tutoral then said to execute Rails *4.2.2* New MyApp. I decided to see what would happen if I did Rails *4.2.1* New Myapp, expecting an error (since 4.2.2 is installed and not 4.2.1 [I think] ), only to get successful execution.

Why is this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that version is available in your default gem set which is associated to the Ruby version you are using. Run `gem list rails` and it will list the rails versions that you have. Try running `rails _4.2.3_ new myApp` but instead of `_4.2.3_` use a version not listed and you will get an error,`Could not find 'railties' (= x.x.x)`  If you install the rails version with `gem install rails -v x.x.x` you will have that rails version available for that ruby version. Also if you `cd` to your application and run `rails -v` it will output the rails version of that one application.

Comment: I think I understand - if my working directory wasnt the application (higher in tree), would rails -v just show the latest version then ?